# unable to make a Compute Engine Instance in Asia-south1

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm unable to make a Compute Engine Instance in Asia-south1.
I see there is some quota limit, but I thought after activating the account there won't be this sort of limits. Is there anyway to run an instance in Asia-south.

[image]

Comment: Please provide some more information about error-messages and your approach to create a instance. Did you just click around in the web-console?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you're receiving error `The zone 'projects/XXX/zones/asia-south1-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.`

I tried creating a VM in asia-south1 (a,b and c) on my account and was also unable.
This situation is not caused by your quota, you can find explanation in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-vm-creation#vm-not-created):

> If you receive a resource error when requesting new resources, the
> zone you requested the resources in cannot currently accommodate your
> request. This error is due to the availability of Compute Engine
> resources in the zone, and is not due to your Compute Engine quota.

You can either wait for resources to be released, create machine in different region or make a [Compute Engine reservation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources).